# Passing mappable objects back to observable ViewModel

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, mapping

Given a pretty big Knockout.js ViewModel filled with observables, and corresponding input fields on the View:

```
var PersonViewModel = {
  var name = ko.observable();
  var age = ko.observable();
  // and so on...
}
```

Say I've got an observable array filled with people objects (i.e. `ko.toJS(PersonViewModel)`), which generates a list of people on the View.  For any person in the list, I want users to be able to click on a person to edit their information, and for the person object in the observable array to be overwritten.

Aside from manually updating all of the input fields, how could I use `PersonViewModel` to pull up a *specific* person's information in the input fields?

Can this be done by updating the properties of the ViewModel after bindings are applied / can mappable objects be passed back to the ViewModel?  Could I use jQuery's `$.map()` to map a person object back onto the ViewModel without any consequences, or would this make the ViewModel no longer observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out a way to get this working. If the Javascript object looks something like:

```
var specificPerson = {name: "John", age: 30, etc: "etc..."}
```

and given that the Knockout.JS observable can only be set via:

```
PersonViewModel.name('Jane');
```

Then [you can iterate through a specific person's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties), temporarily store the values, and apply them to the ViewModel:

```
for (var property in specificPerson) {
   var value = specificPerson[property];
   PersonViewModel[property](value);
};
```

In this way, the specific person's properties will appear in the input fields bound to the ViewModel.